# Continuity of a reaching time of a submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ $(n\geq 1)$ and $v\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathcal{O},\mathbb{R}^n)$. For $x_0\in\mathcal{O}$, let $\big(x(t)\big)_{t\geq 0}$ be the solution of

\begin{align*}
& x(0)=x_0 \\
& \dot{x}=v(x).
\end{align*}

Let $V\subset\mathcal{O}$ a submanifold of dimension $n-1$, such that $x_0\notin V$ and, for all $x\in V$, $v(x)\notin T_x(V)$ (where $T_x(V)$ is the tangent space at $x$ of $V$). Denote by $\tau^V(x_0)$ the reaching time of $V$ by the trajectory $\big(x(t)\big)_{t\geq 0}$:

\begin{align*}
\tau^V(x_0)=\inf\big\{t\geq 0,\,x(t)\in V\big\}
\end{align*}

**Question:** If $\tau^V(x_0)<+\infty$, is $\tau^V$ continuous on a neighborhood of $x_0$?

Comment: The flow of $v$ is a diffeomorphism, and then near $V$ you can use the standard proof of the straightening out theorem (flow box theorem) to turn any example into any other, so pick one for which the result is obvious. But this only works for closed $V$, since we could have trouble with slipping off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is closed in $\mathcal{O}$, then $\tau^V$ is continuous at $x_0$. If $V$ is not closed, then it is not hard to find counterexamples (e.g. imagine $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{R}^3$, $V$ is an open disk and $x(t)$ passes through the boundary of the disk and later intersects the disk).

To begin with, let $t_0=\tau^V(x_0)$. We can give local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ for some neighborhood $U$ of $x(t_0)$ so that $V\cap U=\{x^1=0\}\subseteq U$. Now as $v(x(t_0))\not\in T_x(v)$, we can suppose that, for some $\varepsilon>0$, $x^1(x(t))<0$ for all $t\in(t_0-\varepsilon,t_0)$ and $x^1(x(t))>0$ for $t\in(t_0,t_0+\varepsilon)$. As the flow is continuous, there is a neighborhood $W\times(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$ of $(x_0,t_0)\in\mathcal{O}\times\mathbb{R}$ (with $\delta<\varepsilon$) such that $y(t)\in U$ for all $(y,t)\in W\times(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$ (where $y(t)$ is defined by $y(0)=y,y'=v(y)$). Moreover, as $x^1(x(t_0+\delta))>0$ and $x^1(x(t_0-\delta))<0$, shrinking the neighborhood $W$ if necessary we get that $x^1(y(t_0+\delta))>0$ and $x^1(y(t_0-\delta))<0$ for all $y\in W$. So by the intermediate value theorem, for every $y\in W$ there is some $s\in(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$ such that $y(s)\in W$.

As we can make $\delta$ as small as we want, we get that for all $\delta>0$ there is a neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $\tau^V(y)<t_0+\delta\;\forall y\in W$. (We have still not used that $V$ is closed)

Now we just need to prove that for all $\delta>0$ there is a neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $\tau^V(y)>t_0-\delta\;\forall y\in W$. But if this was false for some $\delta$, there would be a sequence of points $p_n\to x$ and a sequence of times $t_n<t_0-\delta$ such that $p_n(t_n)\in V$. As $V$ is closed (and once again using continuity of the flow), this means that for some accumulation point $t\leq t_0-\delta$ of the sequence $t_n$ we have $x(t)\in V$, a contradiction.

Comment: You may want to change notation for the neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$, which conflicts with the codim 1 submanifold $V$.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I didn't notice